# How to make spaCy NER ignore comparisons

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I am trying to parse sentences using spaCy and I want to ignore comparisons, but I have no idea how that is done.

For example if I have the sentence `Java, unlike C, has a garbage collector`.

I only want "Java" to be recognized as the NER that is being addressed in the sentence based on its context.

I am sorry if my title is off, I am currently trying with NER, but maybe I need something else?

Comment: Do you have a list of languages o be recognized or you want Spacy to do that? (In the last case I guess it is quite error prone)

Comment: Just English is okay

Comment: I mean a list of programming languages. You want to ignore comparisons between what? whatever?

Comment: It is not just for programming languages. Any comparisons in a sentense.

Mercedes, unlike Toyota, is a german car manufacturer. 

Bob, similarly to Mike is a football player.

Named Entity Recognision finds Mercedes & Toyota , Bob & Mike, but I want to enhance it to exclude comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only NER will not allow you to do that.

By using a parser in combination with NER you should be able to identify the subject (`nsubj`) of your sentences, which seem to be the words of interest to you.

You will need to use a good model, though. I got good results on the example you gave in comment using `en_core_web_trf`.